# iOS - Missing Data app Document Folder

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an app that maintains its data in the app document folder such as SQLLite and pictures and unfortunately I notice that when the SIM chip is replaced with a different number the app opens without any information completely empty, if i replace it back with the old SIM the data appears again.

Looks like that the document folder is changed according to the SIM inserted on the phone, is this correct?

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

thanks in advance

Regards,

FP

Comment: I can not reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Update your question with code showing how you access the data in the Documents folder.